# Troubles with import in Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, import

I have the following error when try to compile:

```
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:5:1: ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol" not found: Deferred import import "../utils/Context.sol"; ^----------------------------^
```

I use Remix IDE and error occurred on the following line:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: i guess it is because in openzeppelin ownable contract the path is  
`
import "../utils/Context.sol";
`
rather than the full path is 
`
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
`

but i am not sure how to fix it properly, i changed the path in remix (after click to the error the ownable contract opened) but it didnt fix

Answer (score 2):

fixed the problem with import all dependencies. just imported explicitly the contract `Context.sol` which path is used locally in the `Ownable.sol`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```